# DAX only count first occurrence

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular, ssas-2016

I have the following tables in a SSAS 2016 Tabular model:

- fact_ContactScore (inluding foreign key to dim_account and a measure TopContact)
- dim_Account (has accountname and parentaccountname)

An account can have multiple records in the fact_ContactScore where TopContact is either 1 or 0 and a parentaccount can have multiple accounts. The requirement is to create a measure to:

- return 1 for an accountname if the sum of TopContacts for that accountname >= 1
- return 1 for a parentaccountname if the sum of TopContacts for that parentaccountname >= 1

I tried several options including the following links but none of these worked:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/90330e64-89de-49f4-85e1-399d8a3fd48b/count-only-first-occurence?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel

[DAX First Occurance in SUMMARIZE, FIRST_VALUE equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226695/dax-first-occurance-in-summarize-first-value-equivalent)

Comment: have you tried the rank + filter pattern?

Comment: I was able to change the model and use bidirectional filtering between the fact and the dim.